# How to create Edge rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have latest clone for rails source code.

I want to create apps with the help of rails latest commit. I am not going to use those apps in production. Just for experimentation.

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 22):

I put up [a gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/3025502) for how to create a Rails app using EdgeRails (currently what is to become the Rails 4 release). The gist of it (no pun intended) is that you do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/rails/rails.git
rails/railties/bin/rails new myapp --edge
```

This will create a new app skeleton based on current EdgeRails and it will point the Gemfile to Rails on Github. If you would like to point the Gemfile to your local checkout instead, use the --dev option (for example to experiment with changes to Rails):

```
rails/railties/bin/rails new myapp --dev
```

Comment: Update: the `rails` script have moved from `bin` to `exe`, so, now the command is the following:
`rails/railties/exe/rails new myapp --edge`

Answer (score 11):

Peter's suggestion works well for Rails 4, but in order to run Rails 5 edge I had to take slightly different steps.

At the time of writing, Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2.  Make sure you using Ruby 2.2.2, then do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/rails/rails.git
cd rails/
bundle install
cd ../
./rails/railties/exe/rails new myapp --edge --dev
```

Answer (score 10):

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails',
    :git => 'http://github.com/rails/rails.git'
```