# Rails 4 edge install on mt lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I install rails 4.0, bleeding edge (master branch on git) on my Mac? Can I do it with RVM?

I'm doing this to start upgrading a project, not a new project.

Answer (score 25):

rails 4 is coming!!!

`gem install rails --version 4.0.0.beta1 --no-ri --no-rdoc`

Comment: Oh, BTW, you'd better upgrade to ruby 2.0.0p0 or higher as well. Matz said it's 100% compatible with the old rubies. So go ahead and take your boots wet :)

Answer (score 7):

In your gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'arel',  :git => 'git://github.com/rails/arel.git'
gem 'rack',  :git => 'git://github.com/rack/rack.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using a recent patch level of Ruby 1.9.3.

```
git clone https://github.com/rails/rails.git
ruby rails/railties/bin/rails new APPNAME --dev
cd APPNAME
bundle install
bundle exec rails s
```

This way bundler references gem sources from your local directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a solid answer

http://stufftohelpyouout.blogspot.com/2012/09/install-local-edge-rails-40-beta-and.html

Process stays the same more-or-less. You need to checkout rails from git and then use it to generate your new file.

the --pre flag should work soon enough :)

Comment: And here's a simple SO version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821077/how-to-create-edge-rails-application