# enum query not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have a User model with the following enum declaration

```
 enum access_level: [:general, :marketing, :admin]
```

There is only one user that is :admin and the rest are :general.
The following work correctly

```
User.admin.count # returns 1
User.where(access_level: 2).count # returns 1
```

but

```
User.where(access_level: :admin).count # returns 0
```

instead of `1`.  According to the [edge api](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) page `User.where(access_level: :admin)` should work.  I do not want to use `User.where(access_level: 2)` as it is not as maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the version of rails you are using does not yet have the functionality described in the Edge Guides.

The [4.2 version of the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) do not mention the `User.where(access_level: :admin).count` syntax.

According to http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/:

> These are Edge Guides, based on the current master branch.

If you want this functionality, have a look at this SO answer to see [How to create Edge rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821077/how-to-create-edge-rails-application).

Comment: Thank you, I am using rails 4.2.